# Python script through PHP wrapper OpenBLAS error

Tags: python, php, blas, openblas

I'm trying to run a python script as a cronjob via a PHP wrapper. The webserver is a shared one.

When I'm running `./script.py` via PuTTY on the server everything runs fine.

I now want to implement a cronjob to start the script everyday. I implemented a very simple wrapper in PHP

`echo shell_exec("./script.py");`

and get the error

> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 29 of 40:
> Resource temporarily unavailable
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init:
> RLIMIT_NPROC 42 current, 42 max

I already changed `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` and every other thinkable variable to limit the thread counts. I chmod'ed everything to 777. I also checked if the webserver user is the same as the PuTTY user. I'm at the end of my wits, thanks.